# How can I "remove" the disabled attribute on click?

Tags: jquery

I couldn't quite get it to work properly. I'm trying to remove the disabled attribute on click so that I can edit it.

My jQuery:

```
$('#edit-credentials').click(function() { 
    $('#credentials :input').prop("disabled", !$('#credentials:input').prop("disabled")) 
});
```

HTML:

```
<a id="edit-credentials" onclick="return false;" href="#">edit</a>

<div id="credentials">
<input disabled="disabled">
<input disabled="disabled">
</div>
```

Comment: Are you trying to toggle the disabled property?

Comment: can you post the `credentials` part? also, just a guess- try to remove the `return false` bit..

Answer (score 4):

What wrong with

```
$('#credentials :input').prop("disabled", false);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can remove disable attribute from input via

```
$('#credentials :input').removeAttr("disabled");
```

Comment: I read that `prop()` is the new `attr()` and that you should avoid `attr()` from now on.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
$("#edit-credentials").click(function() {
  $('#credentials :input').removeAttr("disabled");
});
```

Comment: I read that `prop()` is the new `attr()` and that you should avoid `attr()` from now on.

Comment: "".attr() should not be used on plain objects, arrays, the window, or the document. To retrieve and change DOM properties, use the .prop() method.

Using jQuery's .attr() method to get the value of an element's attribute has two main benefits:

    Convenience: It can be called directly on a jQuery object and chained to other jQuery methods.
    Cross-browser consistency: The values of some attributes are reported inconsistently across browsers, and even across versions of a single browser. The .attr() method reduces such inconsistencies.""

Answer (score 0):

I just figured out why. I missed a space. I even copied the mistake here into the original post!

```
$('#edit-credentials').click(function() { 
    $('#credentials :input').prop("disabled", !$('#credentials:input').prop("disabled")) 
});
```

The space added in the `#creditials :input`.

```
$('#edit-credentials').click(function() { 
    $('#credentials :input').prop("disabled", !$('#credentials :input').prop("disabled")) 
});
```